# Как выровнять формы в Symfony 3 относительно друг друга?

Tags: form, symfony3

Здравствуйте. Как возможно выровнять название полей и сами поля относительно друг друга? Или хотябы сделать так, чтобы названия полей находились над полем для ввода текста (так, как выполнены Created at и Updated at) ?

[image: Как выглядит]

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1 class="text-center">Создание заявки</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="text-center">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg center-block    active" value="Отправить заявку" />
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    <a type="button" class="btn btn-link center-block active" href="{{ path('post_index') }}">Вернуться к просмотру заявок</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам 2 варианта:

1. Оберните слова в тег `<p> </p>`, и тогда ваши поля будут не в той же строке а в новой
2. Используйте **CSS**. Добавьте для всех полей атрибут `clear` со значением `both`. (Значение **Both** - отменяет обтекание элемента одновременно с правого и левого края).

Comment: Проблема в том, что всё (слова и формы) находятся в {{ form_start(form) }} ... {{ form_end(form) }}, а как добраться до текста - я не знаю, т.к. с symfony работаю буквально день.

Comment: @Andrew, тогда можно с помощью **CSS** убрать обтекание элемента, точнее с помощью атрибута `clear`